# How to detect a Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

Many of us don't have a background on functional programming, and much less on category theory algebra. So let's suppose that we need and therefore create a generic type like

```
data MySomething t = .......
```

Then we continue programming, and using `MySomething`. What evidences should alert us that `MySomething` is a monad, and that we have to make it one by writing `instance Monad MySomething ...` and defining `return` and `>>=` for it?

Thanks.

Edit: See also this question: [is chaining operations the only thing that the monad class solves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261427/is-chaining-operations-the-only-thing-that-the-monad-class-solves), and this answer [a monad is an array of functions with helper operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21813760/286335)

Comment: If you suspect it might be a functor, check if it obeys the [functor laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor). If you then suspect it might also be a monad, check if it obeys the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws). To really answer your question, though: If you find yourself writing `fmap`, `return` and `>>=` "accidentally", you might be looking at a monad. Then you verify.

Comment: [This is my take on the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20299094/1463507).

Comment: Why "`t` only appears once in ..."?  You could give plenty of valid definitions of a monad where `t` appears more than once in the data definition.

Comment: @cibercitizen1: Mine is almost an empty statement. kqr's linked answer is good.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 A list "holds more than one value of a", yet you can make that a monad!

Comment: @cibercitizen1 It is an answer to the other question! I don't quite have the time to rewrite it here, and answers that only contain links are generally discouraged.

Comment: we could say that *functors*, whether monadic, applicative or plain, are about ["embellished application"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962626/849891). 'applicative' adds chaining, and 'monad' adds dependence (i.e. creating the next computation step depending on results from a previous computation step).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A big step forward for me in my understanding of monads was the post [Monads are Trees with Grafting](https://github.com/dpiponi/grafting3/blob/master/monads.pdf). If your type looks like a tree, and the `t` values appear at the leaves, then you may have a monad on your hands.

#### Simple examples

Some data types are obviously trees, for example the `Maybe` type

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

which either has a null leaf, or a leaf with a single value. The list is another obvious tree type

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

which is either a null leaf, or a leaf with a single value and another list. An even more obvious tree is the binary tree

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Bin (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

with values at the leaves.

#### Harder examples

However, some types don't look like trees at first glance. For example, the 'reader' monad (aka function monad or environment monad) looks like

```
data Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

Doesn't look like a tree at the moment. But let's specialize to a concrete type `r`, for example `Bool` --

```
data ReaderBool a = ReaderBool (Bool -> a)
```

A function from `Bool` to `a` is equivalent to a pair `(a,a)` where the left element of the pair is the value of the function on `True` and the right argument is the value on `False` --

```
data ReaderBool a = ReaderBool a a
```

which looks a lot more like a tree with only one type of leaf - and indeed, you can make it into a monad

```
instance Monad ReaderBool where
    return a = ReaderBool a a
    ReaderBool a b >>= f = ReaderBool a' b'
      where
        ReaderBool a' _ = f a
        ReaderBool _ b' = f b
```

The moral is that a function `r -> a` can be viewed as a big long tuple containing many values of type `a`, one for each possible input - and that tuple can be viewed as the leaf of a particularly simple tree.

The state monad is another example of this type

```
data State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

where you can view `s -> (a, s)` as a big tuple of values of type `(a, s)` -- one for possible input of type `s`.

One more example - a simplified IO action monad

```
data Action a = Put String (Action a)
              | Get (String -> Action a)
              | Return a
```

This is a tree with three types of leaf -- the `Put` leaf which just carries another action, the `Get` leaf, which can be viewed as an infinite tuple of actions (one for each possible `String` input) and a simple `Return` leaf that just carries a single value of type `a`. So it looks like it might be a monad, and indeed it is

```
instance Monad Action where
  return = Return

  Put s a  >>= f = Put s (a >>= f)
  Get g    >>= f = Get (\s -> g s >>= f)
  Return a >>= f = f a
```

Hopefully that's given you a little bit of intuition.

Thinking of monads as trees, the `return` operation as a way of getting a simple tree with one value, and the `>>=` operation as a way replacing the elements at the leaves of the tree with new trees, can be a powerful unifying way to look at monads.

Comment: Good point. Thx. I conclude that "X is monad => X is a transversable data structure. Right? Is the opposite true? " X is a TDS => X is a monad?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Neither `Traversable` or `Monad` imply one another. In particular, you can't define `returnT :: Traversable t => a -> t a` or  `traverseM :: Monad m, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> m a -> f (m b)`.

Comment: unfortunately the link is outdated

Comment: I've updated the link to point to the blog post, which links to the PDF. I've asked the blog author if he can update the link to the PDF. As of right now, though, the PDF is not accessible.

Comment: can I conclude that `data Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }` has infinity data constructors since `r` can be infinity types whose cardinalities are different so that the tuple types are different?

Answer (score 7):

It's worth mentioning that there isn't a direct way of noticing something is a Monad—instead it's a process you go through when you suspect something may be a Monad to prove that your suspicion is correct.

That said, there are ways to improve your sensitivity to Monads.

#### Know the dependencies

For any type `T`, a law-abiding `instance Monad T` implies that there's a law-abiding `instance Applicative T` and a law-abiding `instance Functor T`. Oftentimes `Functor` is easier to detect (or disprove) than `Monad`. Some computations can be easily detected by their `Applicative` structure before seeing that they're also a `Monad`.

For concreteness, here's how you prove any `Monad` is a `Functor` and an `Applicative`

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Wrapped m a = W { unW :: m a } -- newtype lets us write new instances
  deriving ( Monad )

instance Monad m => Functor (Wrapped m) where
  fmap f (W ma) = W (ma >>= return . f)

instance Monad m => Applicative (Wrapped m) where
  pure = W . return
  W mf <*> W mx = W $ do
    f <- mf
    x <- mx
    return (f x)
```

Generally, the best resource available for understanding this hierarchy of types is the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/e/e9/Typeclassopedia.pdf). I cannot recommend reading it enough.

#### Know your standard monads and transformers

There's a pretty standard set of simple monads that any intermediate Haskell programmer should be immediately familiar with. These are `Writer`, `Reader`, `State`, `Identity`, `Maybe`, and `Either`, `Cont`, and `[]`. Frequently, you'll discover your type is just a small modification of one of these standard monads and thus can be made a monad itself in a way similar to the standard.

Further, some `Monad`s, called *transformers*, "stack" to form other `Monad`s. What this means concretely is that you can combine a (modified form of the) `Reader` monad and a `Writer` monad to form the `ReaderWriter` monad. These modified forms are exposed in the `transformers` and `mtl` packages and are usually demarcated by an appended `T`. Concretely, you can define `ReaderWriter` using standard transformers from `transformers` like this

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer

newtype ReaderWriter r w a = RW { unRW :: ReaderT r (Writer w) a }
  deriving Monad

-- Control.Monad.Trans.Reader defines ReaderT as follows
--
--     newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
--
-- the `m` is the "next" monad on the transformer stack
```

Once you learn transformers you'll find that even more of your standard types are just stacks of basic monads and thus inherit their monad instance from the tranformer's monad instance. This is a *very* power method for both building and detecting monads.

To learn these, it's best to just study the modules in the `transformers` and `mtl` packages.

#### Watch for sequencing

Monads are often introduced in order to provide explicit sequencing of actions. If you're writing a type which requires a concrete representation of a sequence of actions, you may have a monad on your hands—but you might also just have a `Monoid`.

[See this previous answer of mine for a rather in-depth discussion of how a certain sequence could be written as a `Monad`... but derived no advantage from doing so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884548/monad-with-no-wrapped-value/19886123#19886123). Sometimes a sequence is just a list.

#### Know the extensions

Sometimes you'll have a data type which is not obviously a monad, but is obviously something that depends upon a monad instance. A common example is parsing where it might be obvious that you need to have a search that follows many alternatives but it's not immediately clear that you can form a monad from this.

But if you're familiar with `Applicative` or `Monad` you know that there are the `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` classes

```
instance Monad m => MonadPlus m where ...
instance Applicative f => Alternative f where ...
```

which are useful for structure computations which take alternatives. This suggests that maybe there's way to find a monad structure in your type!

#### Know the free structure

There's a notion of the *free* monad on a functor. This terminology is very category theory-esque but it's actually a very useful concept because any monad can be thought of as interpreting a related free monad. Furthermore, free monads are relatively simple structures and thus it's easier to get an intuition for them. Be aware that this stuff is fairly abstract and it can take a bit of effort to digest, though.

The free monad is defined as follows

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Fix (f (Fix f a))
```

which is just the fixed point of our functor `f` adjoined to a `Pure` value. If you study type fixpoints (see the [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) package or Bartosz Milewski's [Understanding F-algebras](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras) for more) you'll find that the `Fix` bit just defines any recursive `data` type and the `Pure` bit allows us to inject "holes" into that regular type which are filled by `a`s.

The `(>>=)` for a `Free` `Monad` is just to take one of those `a`s and fill its hole with a new `Free f a`.

```
(>>=) :: Free f a -> (a -> Free f a) -> Free f a
Pure a >>= g = g a
Fix fx >>= g = Fix (fmap (>>= g) fx) -- push the bind down the type
```

This notion is very similar to Chris Taylor's answer---Monads are just tree-like types where `(>>=)` grafts new tree-like parts where leaves used to be. Or, as I described it above, Monads are just regular types with `Pure` holes that can be filled later.

Free monads have a lot more depth in their abstractness, so I'd recommend Gabriel Gonzalez's [*Purify your code with free monads*](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html) article which shows you how to model complex computation using free monads.

#### Know the canonical decompositions

The final trick I'm going to suggest combines the notion of the free monad and the notion of sequencing and is the basis for new generic monad packages like [`extensible-effects`](http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-12-04-24-days-of-hackage-extensible-effects.html).

One way to think of monads is as a set of instructions executed in sequence. For instance, the `State` monad might be the instructions

```
Get :: State s s
Put :: s -> State s ()
```

Which we can represent concretely as a Functor in a slightly unintuitive manner

```
data StateF s x = Get (s -> x) | Put s x deriving Functor
```

The reason we introduce that `x` parameter is because we're going to sequence `StateF` operations by forming the fixed-point of `StateF`. Intuitively this is as if we replaced that `x` by `StateF` itself so that we could write a type like

```
modify f = Get (\s -> Put (f s) (...))
```

where the `(...)` is the next action in the sequence. Instead of continuing that forever, we use the `Pure` constructor from the `free` monad above. To do so we also have to mark the non-`Pure` bits with `Fix`

```
-- real Haskell now
modify f = Fix (Get $ \s -> Fix (Put (f s) (Pure ()))
```

This mode of thinking carries on a lot further and I'll again direct you to [Gabriel's article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html).

But what you can take away right now is that sometimes you have a type which indicates a sequence of events. This can be interpreted as a certain kind of canonical way of representing a `Monad` and you can use `free` to build the Monad in question from your canonical representation. I *frequently* use this method to build "semantic" monads in my applications like the "database access monad" or the "logging" monad.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the easiest way to find out and simultaneously build an intuition for monads is to just try to implement `return` and `(>>=)` for your type and verify that they satisfy the monad laws.

Answer (score 3):

You should be on the lookout if you end up writing any operations that have signatures that look like any of these—or just as importantly, if you have a number of functions that can be refactored to use them:

```
----- Functor -----

-- Apply a one-place function "inside" `MySomething`.
fmap :: (a -> b) -> MySomething a -> MySomething b

----- Applicative -----

-- Apply an n-place function to the appropriate number and types of 
-- `MySomething`s:
lift :: (a -> ... -> z) -> MySomething a -> ... -> MySomething z

-- Combine multiple `MySomething`s into just one that contains the data of all
-- them, combined in some way.  It doesn't need to be a pair—it could be any 
-- record type.
pair :: MySomething a -> ... -> MySomething z -> MySomething (a, ..., z)

-- Some of your things act like functions, and others like their arguments.
apply :: MySomething (a -> b) -> MySomething a -> MySomething b

-- You can turn any unadorned value into a `MySomething` parametrized by
-- the type
pure :: a -> MySomething a

-- There is some "basic" constant MySomething out of which you can build 
-- any other one using `fmap`.
unit :: MySomething ()

----- Monad -----

bind :: MySomething a -> (a -> MySomething b) -> MySomething b
join :: MySomething (MySomething a) -> MySomething a

----- Traversable -----

traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> MySomething a -> f (MySomething b)
sequence :: Applicative f => MySomething (f a) -> f (MySomething a)
```

Note four things:

1. `Applicative` may be less famous than `Monad`, yet it's a very important and valuable class—arguably the centerpiece of the API!  A lot of things that people originally used `Monad` for actually only require `Applicative`. It's a good practice not to use `Monad` if `Applicative` will do.
2. Similar remarks could be made of `Traversable`—a lot of functions that were originally written for `Monad` (`sequence`, `mapM`) in fact only require `Traversable` + `Applicative`.
3. As a consequence of the above, oftentimes the way you'll discover something is a `Monad` is by first discovering that it's an `Applicative` and then asking whether it's also a `Monad`.
4. Don't forget the laws—they're the authoritative arbiter of what makes it and what doesn't.