# What does this functor in Haskell mean?

Tags: haskell

How can I interpret this expression?

```
:t (+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100)
```

Since `<$>` and `<$>` have the same priority and are left-associative. I think it would be same to `((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100)`. However, I have no clue what it does. In [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors), it is mentioned that

> When we do `(+) <$> (+10) <*> (+5)`, we're using + on the future return values of `(+10)` and `(+5)`, and the result is also something that will produce a value only when called with a parameter.

It sounds to be right-associative. Could anyone explain it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it sounds to be right-associative", I don't see anything that implies that in the quoted sentence, and your previous sentence reasoning about how this is evaluated is correct. As for how this expression is evaluated, in the context of the Applicative instance for "functions with a fixed argument type" see [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961639/applicative-functor-evaluation-is-not-clear-to-me). (It's arguably a duplicate, but perhaps your actual question is slightly different - it's unclear to me.)

Comment: I find it simpler to ignore the details of how `<$>` and `<*>` are defined, and simply remember as an idiom that `f <$> g1 <*> g2 <*> ... <*> gn` is the function `\x -> f (g1 x) (g2 x) ... (gn x)`. That is, it's a function which applies each `g` to the argument before passing the `g` results to `f`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for the reference; that is also quite helpful. I have wrongly implied the left associativity due to the sentence "use + on the future return values of (+10) and (+5)". I wrongly assumed that (+10) and (+5) were evaluated first, then we applied (+) to both results.

Answer (score 7):

The expression:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100)
```

will use the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for a *function* in Haskell. Indeed, `a -> b` is short for `(->) a b` with `(->)` a type constructor. So we can define instances as `Functor (->) a` to work with  a function. The [`Functor` <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1014) and [`Applicative` <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1018) instances are defined as:

> ```
> instance Functor ((->) r) where
>     fmap = (.)
>
> instance Applicative ((->) r) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
> ```

The `fmap` on a function thus acts as a "post-processor": it convers a function `a -> b` into a function `a -> c` if the first operand is a function `b -> c` by applying that function on the result of the first function.

The `Applicative` will take two functions `f :: a -> b -> c` and `g :: a -> b` and thus construct a function that maps `x` on `f x (g x)`.

If we thus look at the expression:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100)
```

Then this is equivalent to:

```
(<*>) (fmap (+) (+3)) (*100)
```

The `fmap` thus is equivalent to `(.)`, so this is:

```
(<*>) ((+) . (+3)) (*100)
```

or:

```
(<*>) (\x -> ((x+3) +)) (*100)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
\y -> (\x -> ((x+3) +)) y ((*100) y)
```

We can simplify this to:

```
\y -> (y+3) +) (y*100)
```

and thus:

```
\y -> (y+3) + (y*100)
```

It thus produces a function will map `y` to `y + 3 + (y * 100)`. It will thus apply `y` to both `(+3)` and `(*100)` and then adds these together because of the `(+)` before the `<$>`.

The rule in general is thus that:

```
g <$> f1 <*> f2 <*> … <*> fn
```

with `fi :: a -> bi` and `g :: b1 -> b2 -> … -> bn -> c`, then it creates a function that will map a variable `x` to `g (f1 x) (f2 x) … (fn x)`.